# generating different keys RSA in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I want to generate 2 uniq pairs of public/secret keys using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. Here is my code

```
public static byte[] publicKeyAlice, publicKeyBob, privateKeyAlice, privateKeyBob, publicKeyTrent, privateKeyTrent;
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(KEY_SIZE))
{
    publicKeyAlice = rsa.ExportCspBlob(false);
    privateKeyAlice = rsa.ExportCspBlob(true);
    privateKeyBob = rsa.ExportCspBlob(true);
    publicKeyBob = rsa.ExportCspBlob(false);
}
```

But when i look at arrays `publicKeyAlice` and `publicKeyBob`, they are identical. Help me, please, to make them different.

Comment: It seems to me you're not generating anything twice. Exporting something is not generating something.

Comment: it seems that you do not understand the RsaCryptoSerivceProvider class, although from its name it sounds like a service that generates KeyPairs, but instead, think of it as the key itself. once you create RSACryptoServiceProvider using its constructor, the KeyPair already created, the ExportCspBlob will only export the already created KeyPair into a blob form. so you need to construct an RSACryptoServiceProvider for each KeyPair.

Answer (score 3):

Create distinct providers for each key pair:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(KEY_SIZE))
{
    publicKeyAlice = rsa.ExportCspBlob(false);
    privateKeyAlice = rsa.ExportCspBlob(true);
}
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(KEY_SIZE))
{
    privateKeyBob = rsa.ExportCspBlob(true);
    publicKeyBob = rsa.ExportCspBlob(false);
}
```

Comment: works for me. Are you saying that for you, publicKeyAlice and publicKeyBob are identical?